# How can I extract the first frame from a movie AND overlay a watermark on it at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to, with a single ffmpeg command line, extract the first frame from a movie (as a .jpg and sized to fit inside a box of a given size), and overlay a centered PNG on that frame.

I've run into problems using -vf and -filter_complex at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -i image.png
   -filter_complex
           "[0]scale=W:H:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[v];
            [v][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2"
  -vframes 1  output.jpg
```

WxH is your box size.